# Apache commons MultiValuedMap and Jackson

Tags: java, jackson, apache-commons, fasterxml

I want to serialize/deserialize MultiValuedMap<String,Object>. Its hard to believe, that there is no example code in www. Does anyone knows an example?

Here is my code snippet
import org.apache.commons.collections4.MultiValuedMap;

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer;

public class MultiValuedMapSerializer extends StdSerializer<MultiValuedMap<String,Object>> {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public MultiValuedMapSerializer() {
    this(null);
  }

  protected MultiValuedMapSerializer(Class<MultiValuedMap<String,Object>> klass) {
    super(klass);
  }

  @Override
  public void serialize(MultiValuedMap<String,Object> value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
    gen.writeStartObject();
    for (Entry<String, Object> entry : value.entries()) {
      if(entry.getValue() instanceOf MultiValuedMap){
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        MultiValuedMap<String, Object> map = (MultiValuedMap<String, Object>) value;
        if (key != null) {
          gen.writeFieldName(key);
          serialize(map, gen, provider);
        } else {
          serialize(map, gen, provider);
        }
      } else if(){....} else if(){....} ...
    }
    gen.writeEndObject();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the fact that `org.apache.commons.collections4.MultiValuedMap` can be easily converted to `Map`. `Jackson` already has a serialiser for it so all corner cases are handled automatically. It could look like below:

```
class MultiValuedMapJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<MultiValuedMap> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(MultiValuedMap value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        if (value == null) {
            gen.writeNull();
            return;
        }

        gen.writeObject(value.asMap());
    }

    @Override
    public Class<MultiValuedMap> handledType() {
        return MultiValuedMap.class;
    }
}
```

Below, you can find an example how to register it and use:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.json.JsonMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
import org.apache.commons.collections4.MultiValuedMap;
import org.apache.commons.collections4.multimap.HashSetValuedHashMap;

import java.io.IOException;

public class JsonMultiValuedMapApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SimpleModule collections4Module = new SimpleModule();
        collections4Module.addSerializer(new MultiValuedMapJsonSerializer());

        ObjectMapper mapper = JsonMapper.builder()
                .enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)
                .addModule(collections4Module)
                .build();

        MapWrapper wrapper = new MapWrapper();
        wrapper.getMap().put("numbers", 1L);
        wrapper.getMap().put("numbers", 2L);
        wrapper.getMap().put("strings", "value");

        mapper.writeValue(System.out, wrapper);
    }
}

class MapWrapper {

    private MultiValuedMap<String, Object> map = new HashSetValuedHashMap<>();

    public MultiValuedMap<String, Object> getMap() {
        return map;
    }

    public void setMap(MultiValuedMap<String, Object> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
{
  "map" : {
    "strings" : [ "value" ],
    "numbers" : [ 1, 2 ]
  }
}
```

Comment: The purpose of a multimap would be to have sth. like '{"json-with-multiple-identical-keys":{"key1":"value1","key1":"value2","key2":true}}'. Thats why the MultiValuedMap.asMap() does not fit, as it is a Map<K, Collection<V>>.

Comment: @hiaclibe, `JSON` which has two or more fields with the same name it is not a good idea. Many libraries, including `Jackson`, would require custom handling. `JSON Array` looks more natural. But, I understand that other side could force to use formats like this. We need to customise `Map serialiser` to handle this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to customize the JSON mapper here is another solution where you use `asMap()` to serialise, then first deserialise into a standard `Map` then copy the entries back to the `MultiValueMap`

Runnable example

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.apache.commons.collections4.MultiValuedMap;
import org.apache.commons.collections4.multimap.ArrayListValuedHashMap;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

class Scratch {

    private static ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MultiValuedMap<String, String> map = new ArrayListValuedHashMap<>();
        map.put("key1", "val1");
        map.put("key1", "val2");
        map.put("key1", "val3");
        map.put("key2", "val4");
        map.put("key2", "val5");
        System.out.println(map);

        String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(map.asMap());
        System.out.println(json);

        MultiValuedMap<String, String> mapFromJson= new ArrayListValuedHashMap<>();

        TypeReference<Map<String, List<String>>> typeReference = new TypeReference<>(){};
        Map<String, List<String>> stringListMap = objectMapper.readValue(json, typeReference);
        stringListMap.forEach(mapFromJson::putAll);

        System.out.println(mapFromJson);
    }
}
```

It will print

```
{key1=[val1, val2, val3], key2=[val4, val5]}
{"key1":["val1","val2","val3"],"key2":["val4","val5"]}
{key1=[val1, val2, val3], key2=[val4, val5]}
```